# Why is there no implicit bitwise comparison in C++?

Tags: c++, comparison-operators

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct S {
    int m_i;
};

int main() {
    S s1;
    // okay - implicit copy constructor
    S s2(s1);

    S s3;
    // okay - implicit copy assignment
    s3 = s1;

    // awkward
    if(s1 == s2)
        cout << "can't be" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

This piece does not compile as expected and, given the age of this design decision and the amount of code that (possibly) depends on it, we are stuck with it forever. Still, does anyone have a hunch about the initial reasons behind it?

Comment: Because comparison is a value-based operation, not a bitwise operation.

Comment: There are proposals for adding *memberwise* comparison to C++, like [this one](http://www.open-std.org/Jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0432r0.html). Might become  part of a future standard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because of the padding bytes, which are not initialized and can therefore have any value.

For example, if `S` is defined as follows:

```
struct S {
    char m_c;
    int m_i;
};
```

between `m_c` and `m_i`, there are padding bytes which could make `s1` and `s2` compare unequal, even if all members have the same value.

Another reason is that some types may have multiple object representations for the same value.

Comment: No more plausible: a compiler will often implement the default copy constructor using a memcpy: upvoted though.

Comment: There is no problem making a copy with `memcpy`, the padding bytes can be copied since they don't matter.

Comment: This only explains why a memcmp is not the right thing to do for default comparisons, but in C++ memcpy isn't the right thing for the default copy either: the compiler must ensure a member-by-member copy (for POD memcpy is ok in this case). So the question should be read as: why isn't there a default member-by-member comparison? And the answer might be: because other than memcpy, memcmp isn't up to snuff with PODs (and people got lazy implementing useful language features)...

Answer (score 4):

If S, say, contains pointers then two instances of S might have the same contents but their pointers might point to different memory (even if the data at those memory locations are identical).

So your scheme will not work in full generality.

Comment: This is an example where `Java` shines!

Comment: That's not the reason - comparing pointers is another business.

Comment: Comparing pointers is not the same but just as valid as comparing the memory the pointers are pointing to